# How to migrate Munin graph history

Tags: migration, munin

I have a pretty basic munin configuration, with a host in my munin.conf like this

```
[old;name]
```

and a Plugin, that gives `host_name: name`

I changed the munin.conf to

```
  [new;name]
```

the host_name in the Plugin remained the same.

Now the Plugin shows, but there's no history (no surprise).
I need to migrate the graph's history. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate the files in /var/lib/munin.  Directory strutcure will be old/name*.  Move the files to new/name*.  You will loose the history between when you made the change and now.

If you plan such moves in the future, create hard links in the new destination before the change.  Then remove the old files after the change.

Comment: than for the tip for future migrations. Is there a chance of merging the data?

Comment: It should be possible to export the data from one RRD file and import them into the other with `rrddump` and `rrdrestore` from the RRDtools (http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool), which is what munin uses to create the graphs.